# Wrong metadata when using cls-hooked

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mqtt, cls, async-hooks

I have an app that connects to the MQTT, I want to publish 1200 devices with the id of each device as a metadata. the following is the code

```
"use-strict"
const RSVP = require('rsvp');
const Mqtt = require('mqtt');
const cls = require('cls-hooked');

const namespace = "firstName";
let clsNamespace;

let client = Mqtt.connect("alis://test.mosquitto.org");


if (!client) {
    logger.Error("Test", 'Init', 'No mqtt client provided');
    throw new extError('No mqtt client created');
}

client.on('connect', async () => {
    console.log("Connected");
    try {
        clsNamespace = cls.createNamespace(namespace);
        main();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});


function main() {
    var devices = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 1200; i++) {
        devices.push({ "id": i });

    }
    RSVP.all(devices.map(async (item) => await updateDevice(item)));
}

async function updateDevice(device) {
    try {
        return await wrapContext(clsNamespace, async () => {
            setContext({ device: device.id });
            console.log("update " + device.id + " metadata =" + JSON.stringify(__getMetadata()));
            return publish("message", device.id);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

}

function setContext(context) {
    try {
        let ctxKeys = clsNamespace.get('contextKeys') ? clsNamespace.get('contextKeys') : [];
        for (const key in context) {
            clsNamespace.set(key, context[key]);
            if (ctxKeys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                ctxKeys.push(key);
            }
        }
        clsNamespace.set('contextKeys', ctxKeys);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        console.log('cannot set context', context);
        throw error;
    }
}

function publish(message, deviceId) {
    return new RSVP.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            client.publish(message,
                deviceId,
                (error) => {
                    if (error) {
                        console.log("error")
                        reject(error);
                    } else {
                        console.log("publish " + deviceId + " metadata" + JSON.stringify(__getMetadata()));
                        resolve();
                    }
                });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }

    });
}

async function wrapContext(cls, callback) {
    let defer = RSVP.defer();
    let context = await cls.run(async (contextObj) => {
        try {
            let result = await callback(contextObj);
            defer.resolve(result);
        } catch (error) {
            defer.reject(error);
        }
    });
    return defer.promise;
};

function __getMetadata() {
    const metadata = {};
    let contextData = {};
    for (const key of clsNamespace.get('contextKeys') || []) {
        contextData[key] = clsNamespace.get(key);
    }

    for (const key in contextData) {
        metadata[key] = contextData[key];
    }
    return metadata;
}
```

the output is the following:

```
update 0 metadata ={"device":0}
publish 0 metadata{"device":0}
update 1 metadata ={"device":1}
publish 1 metadata{"device":1}
... (same thing for 1165 devices)
update 1166 metadata ={"device":1166}
update 1167 metadata ={"device":1167}
update 1168 metadata ={"device":1168}
update 1169 metadata ={"device":1169}
... (same thing until 1199)
update 1199 metadata ={"device":1199}
publish 1166 metadata{"device":1199}
publish 1167 metadata{"device":1199}
publish 1168 metadata{"device":1199}
... (same thing until 1199)
```

As you can see, the metadata is correct for the 1165 first publish log but once there's an interruption in the iteration and the function become asychnronous, the metadata of the first publish will be missmatched.

Is there a way to fix this?